# How do I publish and access jenkins docker container from browser?

Tags: docker

**What I did:**

Created 2 docker containers using the below command and successfully navigated from the browser.

**Docker Setup:**

**Host Machine:** Linux VM Image(Assume IP is *10.1.1.1*)

**Jenkins Docker Command:**

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname jenkins.local \
  --publish 8080:8080 \
  --publish 50000:50000 \
  --name jenkins \
  --restart always \
  jenkins/jenkins
```

**GitLab CE Docker Command:**

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.local \
  --publish 50443:443 \
  --publish 7070:80 \
  --publish 5022:22 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab:Z \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab:Z \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab:Z \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

**Browser Navigation:**

- Jenkins: http://10.1.1.1:8080/ - Success
- GitLab : http://10.1.1.1:7070/ - Success

**What I need to achieve?**

I need to access the docker applications using a friendly URL without the port as given below.

- http://10.1.1.1:8080/ by --> http://gitlab.test.local
- http://10.1.1.1:7070/ by --> http://jenkins.test.local

Comment: you can use nginx reverse proxy to redirect your url to IP:Port. But you have to have a way of dns resolve locally.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same in my mind. Unfortunately , I have zero experience with Nginx

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the DNS resolve approach? Thanks

Comment: i did not know anyway other than installing local dns server like bind.